# Monotonicity of function of two variables

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I have a function of two variables, which I wish to check for monotonicity in the entire function domain. I cant find any formal definition of increasing or decreasing function for multi variable case. Can anybody please guide?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to check for something for which you don’t have a definition? In other words, how can it be useful if you’re not sure what it is?

Comment: There *is* no sensible definition of monotonicity for multivariable functions, because $\mathbb R^2$ is not ordered.

Comment: Hi @BrianM.Scott. I am very sure what it is. It will tell me whether my function is continuously increasing in its domain or not. But the problem is that I dont know how to do it. So I am asking for help here.

Comment: @5xum. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: @Richa: What do you mean by *continuously increasing* for a function of more than one real variable? You’re going round in circles: that concept is meaningless without a notion of monotonicity, which you’re lacking.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, thats why I need help. :)
I will have to look for some other way.

Comment: @Richa Maybe if you tell us some more about the context you are working in, we will better understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: @5xum. I am trying to find the global maxima of a function of 2 variables (there are a few constraints also). I cant find a way to prove that the optima that I have is not juts local (except for graphical, and that I am keeping as a last resort). So if I could prove that the function is monotonic and concave, I will be done. So thats why, I need monotonicity!

Comment: Schur-convexity is another way to possibly define a monotonicity on functions of several variables.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is no general definiton (as mentioned in the comments, there is no total order on $\mathbb{R}^2$, which would be required for a canonical definition of monotonicity of bivariate functions).

Two *possible* definitions, though: let $$f\colon (x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\mapsto f(x,y)$$
be your function.

- First definition: $f$ is said to be *monotone* (non-decreasing) if for all fixed $x_0, y_0 \in \mathbb{R}$, the two functions $f_{x_0}\colon y\in\mathbb{R}\mapsto f(x_0,y)$ and $f_{y_0}\colon x\in\mathbb{R}\mapsto f(x,y_0)$ are monotone (non-decreasing).
  (i.e., monotonicity wrt both projections)
- Second definition: $f$ is said to be *monotone* (non-decreasing) if for all fixed $(x, y),(x', y') \in \mathbb{R}^2$,
  $$(x \leq x' \text{ and } y \leq y' ) \Rightarrow f(x,y) \leq f(x',y')$$
  (i.e., monotonicity wrt a partial order on $\mathbb{R}^2$)

**Edit:** *I had originally written the two definitions are not equivalent. They are, as [Ij Huij's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2488581/75808) below shows. I can't reconstruct what I had in mind at the time, but to be charitable it's probably either very contrived or wrong...*

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I think the second should work for me. Thanks. :)

Comment: How are those two definitions not equivalent? (See Ij Huij's answer below.)

Comment: If the two definitions are equivalent, then why does this not serve as the canonical definition of monotonicity of bivariate functions?

Answer (score 10):

I wanted to add this as a comment for the first answer, but I cannot put comments. The first and the second definition in this answer are equivalent.

If $f$ satisfies the first definition then it satisfies the second. We can see that by sandwiching $f(x',y)$ (or $f(x,y')$) between $f(x,y)$ and $f(x',y')$.

If $f$ satisfies the second definition, by once setting $x = x'$ and once setting $y = y'$ we can see that it is monotone with respect to both projections.

In general, let $\preceq$ be the elementwise inequality on $\mathbf{R}^n$ ($x \preceq y$ if and only if $x_i \leq y_i$ for all $i$). Now, a function $f: \mathbf{R}^n \mapsto \mathbf{R}$ is monotone with respect to this partial ordering when:

$$x \preceq y \Rightarrow f(x) \leq f(y).$$
This is equivalent to requiring that for all $x \in \mathbf{R}^n$
$$f(x) \leq f(x + \gamma e_i) \quad \text{for all } \gamma \geq 0 \text{  and  }i \in\{1,2,...,n\}, $$
where $\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$ is the standard basis for $\mathbf{R}^n$.