# How to know if a two variable function is increasing?

Tags: calculus

I know that a one variable function is increasing within an interval if its derivative is always positive within that interval.

How do I extend this idea of looking at positive derivatives for functions with two variables?

Comment: I would suggest that you begin by defining what you mean by an increasing function of several variables.

Comment: Split the function into its $x$ dependence—$f(x; y = y_0)$—and its $y$ dependence—$f(y; x = x_0$—and see if each one-dimensional function is strictly increasing.  It makes no sense to talk about "always increasing" when the path is not determined.

Comment: Consider this previous question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1198373/monotonicity-of-function-of-two-variables

Comment: The concept of [increasing function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function#Monotonicity_in_order_theory) requires that both the domain and codomain of the given function are [posets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set). With $n\ge 2$, the set $\mathbb R^n$ has no canonical order.

Comment: You might be thinking of partial derivatives?