# Show the quadratic function $W(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)=A\sum_{i} x_i^2+ \sum_{i\neq j} x_ix_j$ is strictly quasi-concave

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functions, convex-analysis, determinant

I posted the question before [show the quadratic function is quasi-concave](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1851786/show-the-quadratic-function-wx-1-x-2-ldots-x-n-a-sum-i-x-i2-sum-i-neq/1857607#1857607). But I can not understand the only answer, and the author delated his account already. I rephrase my question and show my second attempt here.
I have a quadratic function $W(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)=A\sum_{i} x_i^2+ \sum_{i\neq j} x_ix_j$, with $x_i$ nonnegative and $A \in[0,1)$. And w.l.o.g. we can normalize $x_i's$ to between 0 and 1. In quadratic form, it is $W(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)=X^TMX$, where $$M=\begin{bmatrix}
    A & 1 & 1 & \dots  & 1 \\
    1 & A & 1 & \dots  & 1 \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    1 & 1 & 1 & \dots  & A
\end{bmatrix}.$$
I want to show it is quasi-concave. First I checked $W$ is not concave or convex as $M$ is indefinite. A sufficient condition for (strictly) quasi-concavity of $W$ is that $$(-1)^kH_k(x)>0$$ for $k=1,2...,n.$ Where $H_k(x)$ is the $k-th$ order leading principal minor of the bordered Hessian matrix of $W(x)$:$$H(x)=\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 2A+2\sum_{i\neq1}x_i & 2A+2\sum_{i\neq2}x_i & \dots  & 2A+2\sum_{i\neq n}x_i \\
    2A+2\sum_{i\neq1}x_i & 2A & 2 & \dots  & 2 \\
2A+2\sum_{i\neq 2}x_i & 2 & 2A & \dots & 2\\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    2A+2\sum_{i\neq n}x_i & 2 & 2 & \dots  & 2A
\end{bmatrix}.$$
The determinant of this juggernaut (and all its leading principle minors) can be decomposed.
$$H_k(x)=\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 2A+2\sum_{i\neq1}x_i & 2A+2\sum_{i\neq2}x_i & \dots  & 2A+2\sum_{i\neq k}x_i \\
    2A+2\sum_{i\neq1}x_i & 2A & 2 & \dots  & 2 \\
2A+2\sum_{i\neq 2}x_i & 2 & 2A & \dots & 2\\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    2A+2\sum_{i\neq k}x_i & 2 & 2 & \dots  & 2A
\end{bmatrix}.$$
Let the first row except leading 0 to be $D$, the first column except leading 0 to be $C$,  denote the inner $k*k$ sub-matrix to be$$B=\begin{bmatrix}
    2A & 2 & 2 & \dots  & 2 \\
    2 & 2A & 2 & \dots  & 2 \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    2 & 2 & 2 & \dots  & 2A
\end{bmatrix}.$$ Which turns out to be 2 times of matrix $M$. Then $$det(H_k(x))=det(B)det(0-DB^{-1}C).$$ I know the pattern of $det(B).$ to know whether the sufficient condition is satisfied, I just need to know the sign of $-DB^{-1}C$ which is a number.
But as $B$ is indefinite, $B^{-1}$ is indefinite also, and I actually tried to write out $-DB^{-1}C$ but it is long, and I can not see a easy answer. Is the fact $2A+2\sum_{i\neq j}x_i<2n$ for any $j$ helpful?

Can anyone explain the answer in the original post? Or help me to find a way out here? Checking the bordered Hessian is a standard textbook method, but economist normally find shortcut specific to the context, however I am not able to find one.

This is my 3rd attempt:
[image]
But it seems we can not say $XY >=Y^2$ because we do not know the shape of $W(X)=W(Y)=C$, we are yet to prove it. It is possible the projection of $X$ onto $Y$ is shorter than $Y$ even though we assume $X$ is longer than $Y$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have with $\alpha=1-A\in (0,1]$:
$$ M = -\alpha \ 1_n + e e^T$$
where $e^T=[1\ 1 \ ... \ 1]$. We set
$$B(x,y)= x^T M y= -\alpha x^T y + (e^Tx)(e^Ty)\ \ \ \mbox{and} \ \ \ W(x)=B(x,x).$$

We wish to show that $W(x)$ is strictly quasi-concavity on $\Omega={\Bbb R}_+^n$. We note that $W$ is positive on $\Omega$. It suffices to show that if the conditions $x\neq y\in \Omega$ and $1=W(x)=W(y)$ hold then for all $t\in (0,1)$: $W(tx+(1-t)y)- 1=2t(1-t)(B(x,y)-1)>0$. So assume these conditions. We have (for $x_i,y_i\geq 0$):
$$ 2x^T y < x^Tx + y^T y \ \ \mbox{and} \ \ (x^T y)^2 \leq (x^Tx) \ (y^T y)$$
which  implies the inequality:
$$  (e^T x)^2 (e^T y)^2 =(1 + \alpha x^T x) (1+ \alpha y^Ty) > (1 + \alpha x^T y)^2  $$
And from this we have:
$$   (e^Tx)(e^Ty) > 1+ \alpha x^Ty  \ \ \mbox{or} \ \ B(x,y)>1 $$
which is what we wanted to show.

Comment: thanks for help. I am not sure why you define $X^k_{+/-1}$, so I can not see why goes to infinite is incompatible. A function $W$ on a convex set $U\in R^n$ is strictly quasi-concave if for all $x,y\in U$, and all $t\in (0,1)$, $W(x)>W(y)$ implies $W(tx+(1-t)y)>W(y)$. The intuition is, mix between two points should be higher than the lower one.

Comment: in other words, why do we need the path $X^{k}_t$?

Comment: I defined the segment from $t=-1$ to $t=1$ but you may simply look at $x=-ke$ and $y=ke$. Then $W(1/2 x + 1/2 y) = 0$ which is strictly smaller than $W(x)=W(y)=k^2((A-1)n + n^2)$ (the value at end-points), which violates the condition for quasi-concavity

Comment: Oh, i got it. But my domain is $[0,1]$, so this problem would not happen. I am at the positive orthant.

Comment: @Bob OK, sorry. I had missed that condition. Indeed it seems likely that you are right then. I'll think of why...

Comment: Thanks, I got a solution myself and I'll post it soon.

Comment: @Rush, I am reviewing this question. I am wondering if my $x_i's$ are all positive, does it make $W(X)=X^TMX$ always positive, hence $M$ is positive definite and hence $W$ is concave on the positive domain? Or, even if my context gives all positive $x_i's$, I still can not do this when check concavity? I think my test on the Hessian matrix is correct though, the leading principle minors of $M$ is alternating sign, so $M$ is indefinite ($W$ not concave on $[0,1]^n$?).

Comment: When $0<A<1$ then $M$ is not positive definite, which is why there are these complications. I don't really have any idea about how it works with the minors.

Comment: While, for $n=2$, isn't $W(x,y)=A(x^2+y^2)+2xy$ concave?

Comment: No, the eigenvalues of $M=[A\  1; 1\  A]$ are $A\pm 1$ so one is positive the other negative.

Comment: But it is neither convex, the two eigenvalues of the Hessian have opposite signs.

Comment: So even for 2 variables it is indefinite. But when I plot it in a 3-D plot, say $0.5(x^2+y^2)+2xy$, it looks like convexity?

Comment: It is convex in some direction, concave in another. But is it always quasi-concave (on ${\Bbb R}_+^n$). That is given $x$ and $y$, when considering the segment between the two points, the minimum is attained in $x$ or $y$. It's a funny property. Must admit that I didn't know about the definition of quasi-concavity before reading your post (so thanks for introducing me to the subject).

Comment: Thank you for your patience! Quasi-concavity/convexity are termed by mathematical economists when they weaken the concavity/convexity in studying econ problem, hence it is mostly known to economists only.

Comment: By "direction", you mean any direction(of vector), or the direction of a eigenvector?

Comment: Also, what if my points are taken from a convex set in $R^2$? Say, $x^3+y^3=<1$, would that (some kind of trade-offs bwtween $x$ and $y$) make $W$ concave? I am trying to come up with a numerical example to show $W$ is indeed not concave.

Comment: Given $W(x,y)=(x^2+y^2)/2+2xy$, along the segment $(x,y)=(1-t,t)$ you have: $W(1-t,t)=1/2+t-t^2$ (concave) and along $(x,y)=(t,t)$: $W(t,t)=3t^2$ (convex). A characterizzation of quasi-concave is that for every $h\in {\Bbb R}$ the set $\{x\in {\Bbb R}_+^n: W(x)\geq h\}$ should be convex (this is more or less what I used in the proof in my answer).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46494/discussion-between-bob-and-h-h-rugh).