# How to show that $U(x_1,x_2,...,x_n) = 2+ 2 \frac{A_* -A(x_1,x_2,...,x_n) }{ \sum x_i -V_*} $ is quasi-convex

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functions, convex-analysis, determinant

I have a function:

$$ U(x_1,x_2,...,x_n) =  2+ 2 \frac{A_* -A(x_1,x_2,...,x_n) }{ \sum_{i=1}^n  x_i -V_*},$$

where:
$$
A(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)=\frac{ \left(  n-1   \right)\prod^k_{j=1}x_j}{\sum^n_{j=1}\prod_{i\neq j}x_i}=\frac{n-1}{\sum_i \frac{1}{x_i}},
$$

$ 2\leq x_i \leq  n-1$, $n\geq 3$,

and $A_*,V_*$ are some constants values for a given $n$, which can be expressed as: $A_*=\frac{(n-1)^2}{(n-1)^2+1}$, $V_*=2(n-1)$.

I would like to show that the function $U(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$ is quasi-convex given the following constraint:

$\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\leq n(n-1).$

Firstly, I have already checked that $U(x)$ is neither concave nor convex as Hessian matrix is indefinite. Then I have written down Lagrangian with a given constraint to check the boarded Hessian matrix determinants:

$$
L(\lambda,x_1,x_2,...,x_n )= U(x_1,x_2,...,x_n) + \lambda \left( n(n-1) - \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \right)
$$

The bordered Hessian will then have the following form:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0&-1 & \dots & -1 & -1\\
-1 & \frac{\partial^2 L}{\partial x_1^2} & \frac{\partial^2 L}{\partial x_1 \partial x_2}& \dots & \frac{\partial^2 L}{\partial x_1 \partial x_n} \\
\vdots & \frac{\partial^2 L}{\partial x_2 \partial x_1}&\frac{\partial^2 L}{\partial x_2^2}  & \dots & \frac{\partial^2 L}{\partial x_2 \partial x_n} \\
-1 & \vdots  & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
-1 & \frac{\partial^2 L}{\partial x_n \partial x_1}  & \frac{\partial^2 L}{\partial x_n \partial x_2}  & \dots &  \frac{\partial^2 L}{\partial x_n^2}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

I have checked the signs of leading principal minors for some special cases and it seems like they all are non-positive with given constraints ($\leq 0$) as expected. For example, for $n=3$ (it also rather easy to see for $n=4,5$):

$$
D_1=0\leq 0 ,
$$

$$
D_2=-1\leq 0,
$$
$$
D_3=-\frac{8 x_3^2 (x_1+x_2)
   \left(x_1^2+x_1 (x_3-x_2)+x_2
   (x_2+x_3)\right)}{(x_1
   (x_2+x_3)+x_2 x_3)^3
   \left(-n^2+n+x_1+x_2+x_3\right)}\leq 0,
$$

$$
D_4=-\frac{64 x_1^2 x_2^2 x_3^2
   (x_1+x_2+x_3)^2}{(x_1
   (x_2+x_3)+x_2 x_3)^5
   \left(-n^2+n+x_1+x_2+x_3\right)^2 }\leq 0.
$$

The question is: how can one show that it will be true for any arbitrary $n\geq 3$? My professors suggested developing the proof by induction, but I don't see how to make an induction step here. How could I proceed from here?

Thanks in advance for your help!

P.S. I have seen a similar question on the website before:
[Link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1909894/show-the-quadratic-function-wx-1-x-2-ldots-x-n-a-sum-i-x-i2-sum-i-neq?noredirect=1&lq=1), but I don't think that proposed approach works for this puzlle.

*Update 1.* I have tried to find a pattern in the determinants of leading principal minor. It looks like there is one, but I don't think that it is feasible to extract it. I am wondering whether there is an alternative way to establish a quasi-convexity of this function.

*Update 2.* It is possible to show that all the diagonal elements of the bordered Hessian matrix (except for the first one) are positive. I am not sure whether it is helpful though.

Comment: $$A(x_1,\dots,x_n)=\frac{n-1}{\sum_i\frac1{x_i}}$$

Comment: The “following constraint” is redundant, if $x_i\leq n-1.$

Comment: I agree. Should the Lagrangian be rewritten with $n$ constraints for each one of $x_i$'s instead?

Comment: Also, added the neater form of $A(x_1,…,x_n)$ in the main text. Thank you