# Monotone condition for multivariable functions and monotone operators

Tags: multivariable-calculus, operator-theory, monotone-functions, monotone-operator-theory

I am looking for a general definition of monotone condition for a function $G: \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^m$, and since I did not find a unique definition of monotone condition for multivariable function (see [Monotonicity of function of two variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1198373/monotonicity-of-function-of-two-variables)), I was wondering if the definition of monotone operator could be a valid one.

$G: U \subset\mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^m$ monotone if
$$\langle G(u_1)-G(u_2),u_1-u_2\rangle \geq 0,$$
for all $u_1,u_2 \in U$.

Comment: This "monotonicity" is a useful notion currently the subject of active research, but there are other notions too. There is no "unique definition". The question is, what property of these functions are you looking to use? Having a use in mind might help us find the appropriate property (whatever it's called) for your needs.