# Roots of a sum of functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, vector-spaces, roots

Suppose I have a vector function $f(x): \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$, defined as the elementwise application of some real function. I know that this real function is strictly increasing and has image $\mathbb{R}$. The function f(x) thus has only a single root.

How can I show that adding a linear function to $f(x)$ resulting in $g(x) = f(x) + Mx$ will also give a function with a single root on the domain? Also assume that $f(x) \neq -Mx$.

In general, does adding a linear function to some function can increase the number of roots above one?

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the phrase "only one root in the domain".  Therefore, I
advise that you take the following idea with a **large grain of salt**, because
the idea may well **lead nowhere**.  If $x_1 \neq x_2$ with $f(x_1) \neq f(x_2)$,
is it possible for $g(x_1)$ to equal $g(x_2)$?

Comment: Seems to be a very good idea. An example of function would be $f(x) = x+ \sin(x)$, for which $g(x) =\sin(x)$ can have multiple roots. I might have to use Taylor series for this...

Comment: What does "strictly increasing on **some** domain" mean? The domain of $f$ is $\mathbb R^n$, so it is either strictly increasing on its domain, or just on some **subset** of the domain. If it's the latter, you can't conclude that it has only one root.

Comment: To answer your question, adding a linear function to some function with 1 root will not in general increase the number of roots. Take any polynomial $f(x)=ax+b$ with $a\neq 0$. There are infinitely many linear functions $h(x)=cx+d$ such that $f(x)+h(x)$ still has 1 root.

Comment: OK I rephrased the question, forget about "some" domain (by that I meant subset of the domain) and let's say it's the domain.

Comment: I also corrected a mistake, $f(x)$ is a function from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$ defined elementwise

Comment: @RandyMarsh how can you prove that?

Comment: What does it mean for a function $\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^n$ to be strictly increasing? There is no standard order on $\mathbb R^n$ for $n\geq 2$ (see also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1198373/monotonicity-of-function-of-two-variables), so how are you comparing two vectors in $\mathbb R^n$ and deciding which is larger than the other, maybe component-wise? Also, how can I prove what?

Comment: The function is defined element-wise, it's increasing on each argument. So I compare vectors component-wise. As for the proof, I am talking about the statement that " adding a linear function to some function with 1 root will not in general increase the number of roots". I am not sure I understand how what you say after proves it.

Comment: A univariate polynomial over the reals has at most as many roots as its degree. Adding to $f(x)=ax+b$ a polynomial $h\neq -f$, $h\neq -ax$ of degree $1$ does not change the degree. How do you compare $(-1,1)$ with $(1,-1)$, which one is less than the other? If you are comparing component-wise, you need to specify which component takes precedence in the comparison, for example $(a,b)<(c,d)$ if $a<c$ or $a=c$ and $b<d$. But this is not the only way of comparing two vectors. So saying that a function is strictly increasing on $\mathbb R^n$ depends on how we are comparing the vectors.