continuous points of increasing function which has non-negative increments
I'm struggling to show that an increasing and right-continuous function $F:\mathbb{R}^d\to [0,1]$ whic has non-negative increments doesn't have "too many discontinuous points".
Details are below:
Let  $F:\mathbb{R}^d\to [0,1]$ be a function which has following properties:
Incresing
For all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^d$ with $\forall k,x_k\leq y_k,F(x)\leq F(y).$
Right-continuous
$\lim_{\substack{y\to x\\y>x}}F(y)=F(x)$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}^d$. Here, $y>x$ means $\forall k,y_k>x_k$
non-negative increments
There exists a finite measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb{R}^d$ that satisfies
$$\mu((x,y])=F(x,y],\qquad x<y\in\mathbb{R}^d$$
,where
$$F(x,y]=\sum_{u}(-1)^{p(u)}F(u),\qquad p(u)=\sum_{k=1}^{d}1_{\{u_k\neq y_k\}}$$
and the summation extends over all vertices $u$ of $(x,y]$ .
Now, I want to show that there exists $C_1,\dots,C_d\subset \mathbb{R}$ with the following properties:
1.$C_i$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$.
2.$F$ is (left) continuous on $C=\prod C_i$
My attempt
1.I defined "marginal distribution function" $F_1:\mathbb{R}\to [0,1]$ by
$$F_1(x_1)=\lim_{t\to\infty}F(x_1,t,\dots,t)$$
and want to show
$$F(y_1,a)-F(x_1,a)\leq F_1(y_1)-F_1(x_1)$$
for fixed $a\in\mathbb{R}^{d-1}$ and all $x_1<y_1\in\mathbb{R}$.
If I can prove this inequality, I can show the existence of $C_1,\dots C_d$ using Froda's theorem(a monotone function on the real line has at most countable discontinuous poimts.)
Intuitively, this inequality seems trivial and have to be shown, but I can't prove this.(The difficulty is that
$F$ might not be the distribution function of $\mu$.)
(However, I could show that the continuous point of $F$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}^d$ by contradiction.)
2.I defined a measure $\mu^i$ on $\mathbb{R}$ by $\mu^i(A)=\mu(\mathbb{R}^{i-1}\times A\times \mathbb{R}^{d-i})$ and take $C_i=$(continuous points of $\mu^i$'s distribution function). However, I cant show that $F$ is left continuous on $C=\prod C_i.$
I would appreciate any ideas on how to prove this. Thanks.

I would have thought $\lim\limits_{\substack{y\to x\y>x}}F(y)=F(x)$ would be right-continuous rather than left-continuous.

Maybe the answers in  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1198373/monotonicity-of-function-of-two-variables are useful for you.

@Henry ohps, sorry. I edit it

@Steen82 Thanks! However, my aim is not to show that F is increasing. The link might not be useful.
